# Skipping cloning again between steps bitbucket pipelines

Tags: docker, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a setup where a monorepo runs some parallel steps and each step currently does a clone. Each steps adds up extra 1 min cloning time to build time as its repetitive and unencessary.
[image]

As you can see the build setup takes around 1 minutes to clone the repo. Is there a way we can reuse the already cloned code in next step while running parallel steps?

[image]

**Note:** I know we can skip cloning in each step. But as per my testing, it means not having the code ready for the tests. Need a way to share cloned files between steps.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an initial step that does the clone, creates a tar and saves it as an artifact.

all followup steps use clone.enabled=false and then unpack the tar as the first script command.